# About a short proof of Krull principal ideal theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

> How from [this theorem](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/31/4/401.extract) I can get a proof of Krull principal ideal theorem?

I understand that w.l.g. we can prove it for a Noetherian local ring. But why we can consider that $(x)$ is $M$-primary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a minimal prime over $(x)$. Then $PR_P$ is minimal over $xR_P$. The ring $R_P$ is local and $xR_P$ is $PR_P$-primary.

Comment: Why last sentence holds?

Comment: @Aleksandr.A.Shevchenko The radical of an ideal is the intersection of its minimal prime ideals. In our case what's the radical of $xR_P$?